# List tag Overlapping

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently I am doing a project in which datas are binding in a list, but here my list view data are overlapping each other. Below is the screen short[image]

Note: First `li` datas overlap second. How can I automatically increase the height of `<li>` tag with respect to the length of data?

here is my list view CSS:

```
.listInnerLi
{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Gotham-Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: #000839;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); 
    min-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link? There seems to be something else affecting the height which isn't in the CSS you posted.

Comment: Have you tried adding clear:both; or float:left;

Comment: Can provide your HTML code?

Comment: I think there is continue character for an word which make you the problem. use "word-wrap:break-word;" into your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this. Just added height 60px and padding 2px. And removed auto height.

```
.listInnerLi
{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Gotham-Light', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background: #000839;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2); 
    min-height: 60px !important;
height:60px;
    width: 100%;
padding:2px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<style>
   li {
       line-height:2em;
   }
</style>
```